# JQuery finding value of textbox with [] in the ID

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to find the value of a text-box whose `ID` looks like:

`id="filter[default][did.did]"`

I am trying: `var did1 = $('#filter[default][did.did]').val();` but this is not working. Can someone help me out please?

I probably should have said this initially but there are three textboxes that all have that same ID. I tried escaping the characters like you guys said and I am still getting undefined. However each of the textboxes have a unique name:           `filter[default][did.did1_DID_]` could this be used instead?

EDIT: I am still trying to figure this out. I need to get the value using the name and the other example appears it is setting the value instead of getting the value. I tried `var did1 = $('input[filter\\[default\\]\\[did.did1_DID_\\]]').val();` and this is not working

```
var did1 = $('input:text[name=filter\\[default\\]\\[did.did1_DID_\\]]').val();
```

ended up working using the example above

Comment: should be able to escape [] chars. $("#filter\\[default\\]\\[did.did\\]").val()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `escape` the [meta-characters](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),

```
 var did1 = $('#filter\\[default\\]\\[did\\.did\\]').val();
```

`[` , `]` and `.` are meta characters of jquery, you have to escape it while using it as a selector.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5hcju0z8/)